# Any way to show two widget side by side in gmail add on?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I am creating a gmail add on - 
**Requirement**
I want to include a button and key value add-on on the same row - 
**Status**
Currently only one widget can be shown on 1 line 
Is there any way to show two widgets side by side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the screenshot below

[[image: KeyValue with button][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpBs.png)

We got around this by adding a setOnClickAction and setButton method on a key value pair.

Both "Activities" and "+New" are clickable and perform different actions.

```
activitiesListSection.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue()
                                      .setContent("<b>Activities</b>")
                                      .setOnClickAction(saveAction)
                                      .setButton(CardService.newTextButton()
                                                 .setText("+ New")
                                                 .setOnClickAction(saveAction))
                                      .setIcon(CardService.Icon.DESCRIPTION));
```