# Create a Datepicker Widget in Gmail Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am trying to collect a Date input from the user in a Gmail Add-on, but I don't know how to implement a Datepicker Widget in `CardService` (the only way to make a Gmail Add-on). If I look at Google's Gmail add-ons, they have such a widget:

[image]

Any suggestions please on how this can be done ?

Comment: As per documentation, the UI services for [Class DatePicker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker) was [deprecated last December 11, 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker). Try to refer [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/), you may also be interested to [this post](http://www.googleappsscript.org/miscellaneous/date-picker).

Answer (score 3):

In short: **Can't**

Right now, the only way to create addons is to use CardService. However, CardService lacks certain useful widgets, such as DatePicker, MaskedTextInput, etc. However , default google add-ons seem to have much more powerful widgets, and of course the datepicker. I would recommend you to wait or do a workaround by making use of dropdown to select date, month, year, until they make it available for public.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available for everyone.

```
var dateTimePicker = CardService.newDatePicker()
    .setTitle("Enter the date.")
    .setFieldName("date_field")
    // Set default value as Jan 1, 2018 UTC. Either a number or string is acceptable.
    .setValueInMsSinceEpoch(1514775600)
    .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName("handleDateTimeChange"));
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-picker